# Setting/removing CS_DROPSHADOW style for a WinForms form dynamically (C#)

Tags: winforms, forms, shadow, setclasslong

How to do that? I could not find any useful sample for C#. I know I should use SetClassLong/SetClassLongPtr, but here is the definition I only found: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetClassLongPtr.html.

Obviously, I should call GetClassLongPtr with GCL_STYLE to read the current style flags, add or exclude CS_DROPSHADOW, and then call SetClassLongPtr with the changed flag value. But looking at that PInvoke definition, it is not trivial, especially taking into account 32/64-bit systems.

Can anybody give a link or a good example of this? And please, do not provide samples with overwriting CreateParams as this does not work for our dynamic scenario. Maybe, there is another [managed] way to do that?

Comment: This rarely comes to a good end.  Drop shadows are an Aero feature distinct from CS_DROPSHADOW.  It is controlled by the user, not a program.  Changes affect all windows.  It's gone in Windows 8.

Comment: @HansPassant, I do know that. Here is my sistuation. Our .net grid control has an infrastructure called DropDownManager. Its a class which candisplay another custom control as a cell drop-down. We always need it with shadow if its FormBorderStyle is 'None', or we should enable shadow dynamically if its FormBorderStyle is 'Sizeable'; in the latter case, we analyze whether it's WinXP family (OSVersion is 5.x) or whether it's Vista/Win7 with aero enabled: `bool needShadow = ((ver.Major == 5) && (ver.Minor > 0)) || ((ver.Major > 5) && !IsAeroThemeEnabled());`

Comment: @Hans, maybe, I just need to correct the above test expression to ignore the shadow flag for Win8 family (incl. Win Server 2012). I should check `bool needShadow = ((ver.Major == 5) && (ver.Minor > 0)) || ((ver.Major == 6) && !IsAeroThemeEnabled());`. Though I guess SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDROPSHADOW) in my IsDropShadowEnabled function will simply return false for these OS's.

Comment: One more addition. We need to support all systems .NET 4+ can run on, i.e. WinXP-Win8. If the drop-down container form has a simple look (in fact, a 1-pixel black rectangle), the shadow should be added in any case to make this drop-down block more noticeable. If it's sizeable (has the look of a normal overlapped window), then the shadow should be added only if the corresponding aero theme effect isn't used. Sure, the shadow is added only if the user has enabled it using the corresponding system setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I have managed to write:

```
    private void SetSizeableCore(bool value)
    {
        fSizeable = value;
        if (value)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
            DockPadding.All = 0;
            System.Version ver = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
            // Always for WinXP family, but for higher systems only if the aero theme is not in effect
            bool needShadow = ((ver.Major == 5) && (ver.Minor > 0)) || ((ver.Major > 5) && !IsAeroThemeEnabled());
            SetShadowFlag(needShadow);
        }
        else
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            DockPadding.All = 1;
            SetShadowFlag(true);
        }
    }

    private void SetShadowFlag(bool hasShadow)
    {
        if (!IsDropShadowSupported())
            return;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef myHandleRef = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(this, this.Handle);
        int myStyle = iGNativeMethods.GetClassLongPtr(myHandleRef, iGNativeMethods.CS_DROPSHADOW).ToInt32();
        if (hasShadow)
            myStyle |= iGNativeMethods.CS_DROPSHADOW;
        else
            myStyle &= ~iGNativeMethods.CS_DROPSHADOW;
        iGNativeMethods.SetClassLong(myHandleRef, iGNativeMethods.GCL_STYLE, new IntPtr(myStyle));
    }

    private bool IsDropShadowSupported()
    {
        // Win2000 does not have this feature
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version <= new Version(5, 0))
            return false;
        bool myResult = false;
        iGNativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(iGNativeMethods.SPI_GETDROPSHADOW, 0, ref myResult, 0);
        return myResult;
    }

    private bool IsAeroThemeEnabled()
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5)
        {
            bool aeroEnabled;
            iGNativeMethods.DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out aeroEnabled);
            return aeroEnabled;
        }
        return false; 
    }
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.