# Setting CS_DROPSHADOW for a WinForms form after creatin leads to double shadow for other forms

Tags: forms, winforms, shadow, setclasslong

In far 2012 I wrote in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455236/setting-removing-cs-dropshadow-style-for-a-winforms-form-dynamically-c) that we need to turn the system shadow effect for a reuseable form on/off depending on some conditions. The core part of this code looks like this:

```cs
System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef myHandleRef = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(this, this.Handle);
int myStyle = NativeMethods.GetClassLongPtr(myHandleRef, iGNativeMethods.CS_DROPSHADOW).ToInt32();
if (hasShadow)
    myStyle |= NativeMethods.CS_DROPSHADOW;
else
    myStyle &= ~NativeMethods.CS_DROPSHADOW;
NativeMethods.SetClassLong(myHandleRef, NativeMethods.GCL_STYLE, new IntPtr(myStyle));
```

Unfortunately, this way of applying the CS_DROPSHADOW style to a form leads to a serious problem in Windows 10. All forms created after enabling shadow this way have a parasitic double shadow:

[image]

I mean not the form with the CS_DROPSHADOW style applied - I mean all OTHER forms we can instantiate with code like this:

```cs
Form myForm = new Form();
myForm.Show();
```

Is there another way to apply the CS_DROPSHADOW style to an existing form without this weird side effect?